# How do i reference redirected host drives in a remote desktop session

Tags: rdp, remote, desktop, host, rdc

When I remote desktop into a server, for example, local drives and mapped network drives from my host computer appear as  ON .  I can access these drives using Windows Explorer, but I also need to refer to them from a command window (cmd.exe).

For example, I need to run xcopy  < /s /d, so I would like to open a command shell from my remote desktop session and run the xcopy command.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just use the mapping under `net use`.

They won't have a drive letter assigned, just a mapping. Most of the time it will be listed as something like `\\TSCLIENT\C` or similar.

Then just run the command with the path being something like `\\TSCLIENT\C\Users\bob\Desktop` or whatever.

For instance, to get a sorted directory listing of the root of C on my redirected C drive I would type:

`dir \\tsclient\C | sort`

and this would output a sorted list of my remote C drive:

```
Z:\>dir \\tsclient\C | sort


               2 File(s)      4,642,774 bytes
              19 Dir(s)  144,403,460,096 bytes free
 Directory of \\tsclient\C
 Volume in drive \\tsclient\C is Windows8_OS
```